# Prove using epsilon - delta definition of the limit the following problem.

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{x^3 -4}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{4}{5}$$

I have used long division but I got stucked, am I right?

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you did not obtain the answer using the definition of a limit.

Comment: It is continuous function ($x^2 + 1 > 0$), and $f(2) = \frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: long division isn't necessary  in the case.  If $f(x) = \frac{x^3 -4}{x^2 + 1}$, then the $\lim_{x \to 2)} f(x) = f(2) = \frac{8-4}{4+1} = \frac 45$.  But as @Tucker pointed out, it seems you need to prove this using the definition of a limit.

Comment: Use $\delta = \epsilon$.  Or in oher words, for any $\epsilon > 0$ prove that if $|x - 2| < \epsilon$ then $|\frac {x^3 -4}{x^2 + 1} - \frac 45| < \epsilon$.  I'm not sure how you did long division but I'm sure you didn't need to.

Comment: I'd suggest you improve your post by at least explaining the definition of a limit in your post. Then add your attempt to apply it to this particular function.  It doesn't matter if you're attempt is wrong.apply the definition, but we'd like to see some participation from you.

Comment: @fleablood  you mean $|x-2| < \delta.$

Comment: Yeah. Typ9.  But Ivm pretty sure delta = epsilon will do.

Comment: @fleablood  could you show me please how delta = epsilon will do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to see that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $0<|x-2|<\delta$,
$$
\left|\frac{x^3-4}{x^2+1}-\frac{4}{5}\right|<\varepsilon
$$
The expression inside the absolute value is
$$
\frac{(x-2)(5x^2+6x+12)}{5(x^2+1)}
$$
and, assuming $1<x<3$, we have $5x^2+6x+12<75$ and $5(x^2+1)>10$. Therefore, for $1<x<3$,
$$
\left|\frac{(x-2)(5x^2+6x+12)}{5(x^2+1)}\right|<
\frac{75}{10}|x-2|=\frac{15}{2}|x-2|
$$

Comment: Why did u assume that  $1<x<3$? and How did you get this expression $$\frac{(x-2)(5x^2 + 6x + 12)}{5(x^2 + 1)}?$$

Comment: @Idonotknow The condition $1<x<3$ is the same as assuming $\delta<1$, which is not restrictive; this way we can bound below the denominator and above the numerator. The expression was obtained by standard algebra, factoring the numerator after reducing to a single fraction.

Comment: The inequality $$5(x^2 + 1) > 50$$ is reversed.

Comment: @Idonotknow Yes, you're right! I wanted to write $10$ and $50$ came up. Fixed.